# Can't connect springboot to mysql in docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have a springboot application which needs to be dockerized. I am able to build the jar file using the "./mvnw package" if the application is connected to mysql in local using the following datasource.url in application.properties

```
      spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
      spring.datasource.username=root
      spring.datasource.password=root
```

But if I change the datasource.url to this,

```
      spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://mysql-test:3306/test
```

where mysql-test is the mysql image name in docker, it fails to build the jar file. Can anyone let me know what is the issue here?

Comment: I'm not a docker specialist, but I know in order for containers to "see" eachother they have to be in the same network. Did you create a network in docker and run container in the same network?

Comment: How do you start the `mysql-test` image?

Comment: I am new to java springboot , when I refered some articles online what they does is they initially create the jar file and then creates a Dockerfile to copy the jar and run it. I am stuck in the initial step itself. I am not able to build the jar by providing the details of docker-mysql-image in the application.properties

Comment: @Rashin I have the mysql-test image running in background

Comment: That’s not configuration you can “bake in” to your jar file / image.  Say my MySQL runs externally in Amazon RDS, it’s not `localhost` or a Docker Compose name; how can I configure that at deployment time?

Answer (score 0):

*I sent to you a sample of my spring boot application properties;*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobildev?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Turkey
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

You should change the properties due to your project

Comment: Can you tell me how can I connect springboot to mysql in docker and not in  localhost

Comment: I showed you how can you connect mysql and spring boot using the hibernate sequance. I did not use docker but i found something you should try;           
 Use --network="host" in your docker run command, then 127.0.0.1 in your docker container will point to your docker host.